# How to add the root default category to top menu

Tags: php, magento

I am using the top, or how Magento call it, main menu and I'd like to add there the default caregory with all of its subcategories. I am talking about the Default category which is the root for all of other categories in store. I googled a lot and tried to alter a few files generating the main menu but with no luck. Can someone please help?

Comment: Check with these two file: 1) magentoroot/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml
  2) magentoroot/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml

Answer (score 0):

There is only one root category per store. Hence, you have to put all the categories which should be shown in the frontend under the Default category (or the root category you configured under Manage Stores).